# Numpy - Slicing - Step check

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How to use Numpy to find out the steps of an array.

```
input = np.array([1,2.1,3.5,4,5,6,7,8,9])
step = 2
output = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

basically, if the element is above stating number (1) and below the step (2 in the example above), dont form another number.. but if the input element is above previous number (1) + step, form another number that is 3 in this example.

Here is another example:

```
input = np.array([1,2.1,3.5,4,5,6,7,8,9])
step = 3
output = [1,4,7]
```

How to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: is it `[1,2,1,3,5,4,5,6,7,8,9]` or `[1,2.1,3.5,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Comment: Why your first *output* sample contains *3*? Note that *3* is not present in *input*.

Comment: Looks more like a list problem, focusing on a sequence of values, rather than all values considered as a whole.  Write a list version, and maybe we can suggest ways of improving it.

Answer (score 0):

As your first *output* sample contains *3*, which is **not** present in *input*,
I assume that you want to get something like *np.arange*,

- starting from *input[0]*,
- stopping on the last element of *input* (*input[-1]*),
- with the given *step*,
- as a plain list (not a *Numpy* array),

and elements of this sequence need not be present in *input*.

But you want the last element of *input* to be **included** in the result,
if it "fits" with the sequence generated so far (i.e. the last element of
this sequence (so far *7*) + step == input[-1]).

To generate such a sequence you can use the following function:

```
def stepFilter(arr, step):
    frstElem = arr[0]
    lastElem = arr[-1]
    seq = np.arange(frstElem, lastElem, step)
    if seq[-1] + step == lastElem:
        seq = np.append(seq, lastElem)
    return seq.tolist()
```